# Relative layout looks ok in Eclipse, but not on device

Tags: android, android-layout, android-relativelayout

I have the following layout. It looks ok when I view it within the graphical layout view in Eclipse. But when on a phone, this is not reflected.

On a phone the `TextView rowlogmessage` takes up the whole view and the other `TextView`s are crushed at the bottom.

Any ideas why?

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/rounded_corners_white" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/rowlogmessage"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="log message goes here"
        android:textColor="#707070"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/rowlogcreatedat"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="log message created at"
        android:textColor="#707070"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/rowlogcreatedatlabel"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Created at"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_above="@id/rowlogcreatedat"
        android:paddingTop="10dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/rowlogsentserver"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="log message sent to server"
        android:textColor="#707070"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/rowlogsentserverlabel"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Sent to server"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_above="@id/rowlogsentserver"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Put the "I'm taking the **remaining** space" AFTER all the other TextViews (use the relativity attributes to position it above the one it has to be placed over, `rowlogcreatedat`, and align it to the Parent's Top - as now).

Also note that `fill_parent` is deprecated since API Level 8 included.
Use `match_parent`, instead.

Note also that the proper Java naming uses the `camelCaseNamingConvention`, with the first letter being small caps.

Comment: Glad to know that. I'm using this technique too. ;)

Comment: For naming convention. This is not java it is XML.

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_light"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="5dp" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/rowlogmessage"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="log message goes here"
        android:textColor="#707070" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/rowlogcreatedat"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:text="log message created at"
            android:textColor="#707070" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/rowlogcreatedatlabel"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:text="Created at" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/rowlogsentserver"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:text="log message sent to server"
            android:textColor="#707070" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/rowlogsentserverlabel"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:text="Sent to server" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You uses `android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"` in rowlogcreatedat that's why it align bottom of the screen.Your other `TestView`  referencing this rowlogmessage `TextView` or its associated `TextView` so they are also attcached with bottom of screen along with your rowlogcreatedat `TextView`.
Remove `android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"` and then see how it arranged on screen. Also use `match_parent` instead of `wrap_content`.

Answer (score -1):

I would recommend you to change the width from `fill_parent` to `wrap_content`.

And also in eclipse change the device view to that off your phone. By default eclipse uses nexus 5 layout '5 inch' screen.